# "performance metrics" vs. "evaluation metrics"

Tags: machine-learning, terminology

In the context of machine learning, is there any difference between *performance metrics*, and *evaluation metrics*?

Comment: I am still interested in this question.

Comment: So any answer is welcome!

Comment: My impression is that a lot of machine learning terminology is not rigorous - unfortunately - so people seem to use those terms interchangeably. A distinction that I would make is that I *performance metrics* is more specific, since you could evaluate something else than performance, e.g., more general characteristic which is neither "good" nor "bad" to have. In fact, the usage of the word "metric" is bugging me even more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564021/why-are-measures-sometimes-called-metric